# Ruby on Rails Remote Server File Upload Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, storage

I want to upload the file I upload to the remote server with 'Active Storage'. I used this for [activestorage-ftp](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/2.0.5/Net/SFTP) gem.

**The code I wrote is as follows.**

***config/storage.yml***

```
sftp:
    service: SFTP
    user: xxx
    root: /var/www/storage
    host: xxx@10.10.10.10
    password: xxx
```

File upload is successful but files are not visible on the server.

What should I do to upload the file to the server?

Comment: If the file is not visible, how do you know the upload was successful?

Comment: The Active Storage gem does the loading. The auxiliary activestorage-ftp  gem is the upload options to the server.

Comment: @Casper Its the schrödingers cat of programming. Do you mean that the images are not displaying in your rails app?